# Postgres does not use composite index

Tags: postgresql

I have a table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE orders(
    id int NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    order_type_id int,
);
```

And 2 indexes:

```sql
CREATE INDEX ix_orders_created_at ON orders (created_at);
CREATE INDEX ix_orders_order_type_id_created_at ON orders (orders_type_id, created_at desc);
```

Sometimes I want to get all orders sorted by created_at DESC and sometimes I need to get orders of specific type only, also sorted by created_at. For the second case the query is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders
WHERE order_type_id=(SELECT id FROM order_types WHERE name='order_type_name')
ORDER by created_at DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

I expect that postgres will use seconds composite index for such query. But no, postgres uses simple index on created_at, "scans" all table records by date and filters required types.

```sql
                                          QUERY PLAN                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using ix_orders_created_at on orders  (cost=1.68..1663504.64 rows=5747582 width=1471)
   Filter: (order_type_id = $0)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Seq Scan on order_types  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=1 width=4)
           Filter: (name = 'order_type_name'::text)
(5 rows)
```

For orders of frequent types it is acceptable, but for rare or not yet existing types of orders this leads to heavy and long queries scaning a lot of records. How do I force postgres to use composite index instead? "ANALAZE orders" doesn't help.

Comment: Run the subquery separately and use the result as a constant.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why is this happening?

Comment: Because the optimizer doesn't know the value at query planning time, so it doesn't know that using the index will be faster. Try dropping the single-column index.

Comment: I can't drop single column index because I also need to query all records by date.